# Why does my Python function work in the console, but not when called within code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to learn Python by working through the problems on the Project Euler website. I know exactly what I want my code to do, and my method works on paper, but I can't make the code work.

GitHub link: https://github.com/albyr/euler-python/blob/master/euler3.py

I have created two functions, one which works out the factors of the target number, and one which checks whether a given number is prime.

```
# Function that finds all the factors of a given number
def findfactors(n):
    # for i in range(1,int(sqrt(n)+1)):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if n/i == int(n/i):
            factors.append(i)

# Function that checks if a number is prime
def checkprime(n):
    # Trial division
    for i in range(2,int(sqrt(n)+1)):
        if n/i == int(n/i):
            # Number gives a remainder upon division and therefore is not prime
            isprime = False
            break
        else:
            isprime = True
    if isprime == True:
        return True
    elif isprime == False:
        return False
```

I'm sure that to experts that code looks horrible. But it works if I use the Python shell:

```
>>> checkprime(9)
False
>>> checkprime(79)
True
>>> checkprime(factors[3])
True
```

But when I run the program with F5 I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alby/euler-python/euler3.py", line 45, in <module>
    checkprime(factors[i])
  File "/home/alby/euler-python/euler3.py", line 32, in checkprime
    if isprime == True:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'isprime' referenced before assignment
```

If I call the checkprime function from within the program with a hardcoded number (e.g.     `checkprime(77)`) I get no output at all. I'm certain that this is something basic about the way that Python works that I don't understand, but I cannot for the life of me work out what.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You get no output because you're not printing anything - unlike the console, top-level function calls do not automatically print their results when run normally.

Comment: Well the error is quite obvious: If the loop is never entered you're reading a non initialised variable. Generally that's a pretty strange way to write checkprime to begin with, just return true if you get through the loop and false in the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Github code, we can see that you're trying to call `checkprime(1)` (on the first iteration through your last loop).

```
# Check each factor to see if it is prime or compound
for i in range(0,len(factors)):
    print (factors[i])
    # Why can't I call checkprime here, like this? It works in the console.
    checkprime(factors[i])
```

But look at your code:

```
def checkprime(n):
    # Trial division
    for i in range(2,int(sqrt(n)+1)):
        if n/i == int(n/i):
            # Number gives a remainder upon division and therefore is not prime
            isprime = False
            break
        else:
            isprime = True
```

If `n = 1`, then `range(2, int(sqrt(1)+1))` is `range(2,2)` which is empty... so `isprime` never gets set, because the loop body never gets run.

Keep in mind that the arguments to `range()` are a *half-open* interval - `range(x,y)` is "integers starting at x and ending *before* y". Thus `range(2,3) = [2]` and `range(2,2) = []`.

Another issue here is that `findfactors()` is returning `1` as the first factor - this is probably not what you want:

```
def findfactors(n):
    # for i in range(1,int(sqrt(n)+1)):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
```

For prime factorization checking, you probably want to start at `2`, not `1` (since everything is divisible by 1).

---

Also, this code is redundant:

```
if isprime == True:
        return True
    elif isprime == False:
        return False
```

You can really just write this as...

```
return isprime
```

Or you can go one step better and never use `isprime` in the first place - just replace `isprime = True` with `return True` and `isprime = False` with `return False`.

Finally, a shorthand for `int(n/i)` is `n // i` - Python's `//` operator does integer division.

Comment: That's an amazing answer, Amber. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of no output printing, simply use `print(checkprime(77))` instead when running from F5 and you should get your output. When running from a call, python prints nothing (or at least, only prints the last command) by default.